# Read SessionStorage from webView MAUI

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maui, session-storage

I want to get session storage and id_token from webView after the user logs in. on successful login the application is navigated to another webView, before that I want to read some credentials from sessionStorage. But when I try to access Session storage with  `var sessionStorage =  await web_view.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("sessionStorage");` result is always null or empty object {}

It does not mether if I try to read storage before or after the application is navigated result is always null or empty object.

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{    

    private bool _isLoggedIn = false;
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
    }


    private async void web_view_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
       
        _isLoggedIn = NavigationManager.login
            (Navigation, e.Url);

        if (_isLoggedIn)
        {
            var sessionStorage =  await web_view.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("sessionStorage");
        }
    }
    
}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Have you checked this thread [Xamarin Android WebView access to sessionStorage returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51309608/xamarin-android-webview-access-to-sessionstorage-returns-null)?

Comment: I have, and specifying the exact storage key in sessionStorage.getItem("key") works if I create some kind of a button and then click ok it when page is fully loaded, so I guess the problem is in knowing when the page is fully loaded.. I used loaded event but by that time SessionStorage was not available.

Comment: `I used loaded event but by that time SessionStorage was not available.` Is there any log about this problem?